# Report Viewer - Wrap table on same page

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reporting-services, reporting

I have a very simple report that I have created in Visual Studio 2015 that only contains 2 columns.....The issue that I am having is that when I print this, I have several pages with lots of unused space(The columns aren't that wide), and I would like to cut my page count in half by having my table wrap on the same page.

For example, I currently have something like this.
[image]

And I would like to have both columns on one page, like this.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `Columns` property of your report:

1. display `Property` window
2. click on `Report` (grey area outside your page)
3. set `Columns` property to `2`
4. you can also set `ColumnSpacing` property to something different from `0`

Then simply put your 2-columns `Tablix` in the `Column 1`.

Please note that to see the desired output you need to preview/print/export the report; normal view only display one column.

Comment: gadzoox, I thought this was impossible for sure, thanks!